# What does $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_k)$ equal to?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, conservation-laws, differentiation, dirac-delta-distributions

How do we get the gradient in the RHS of (2.15), where $\mathbf{r}_k(t)$ is the position of the moving particle? This is from page 32 in Zangwill's electrodynamics textbook:

> Let $N$ point charges $q_k$ follow trajectories $\mathbf{r}_k(t)$. The charge density of this system of moving point charges is a time-dependent generalization of (2.6):
> $$\rho(\mathbf{r},t)=\sum_{k=1}^Nq_k\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}(t)) \tag{2.14}$$
> We can use the continuity equation to derive the corresponding current density. The particle velocities are $\mathbf{v}_k(t)=\dot{\mathbf{r}}_k(t)$, so the chain rule gives
> $$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=\sum_k q_k\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_k)=-\sum_kq_k\mathbf{v}_k\cdot \nabla\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_k)\tag{2.15}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the chain rule. $\frac{\partial{f(\vec{r})}}{\partial{t}}=\Sigma_i \frac{\partial{f(\vec{r})}}{\partial{r_i}}\cdot \frac{\partial{r_i}}{\partial{t}} = \Sigma_i \frac{\partial{f(\vec{r})}}{\partial{r_i}}\cdot v_i =  \nabla f(\vec{r}) \cdot \vec{v}$